# How do I get access rights in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I am new to Raspberry and I am trying to access Libre Office however I am being denied since *I don't have the access rights*.

I just recently installed Raspbian so everything is at default including my username and password.

Yet I haven't been asked for my password or username at any point, when I connect it to a power it automatically logs in.

How do I get my access rights?

**Edit**
I am using latest version of everything since I set it up yesterday. 
Specifically I use Raspbian Jessie (it says kernel 4.1 in its website). I just click the icon from GUI menu and nothing else, yet it do not let me open it.

Comment: It's difficult to give any help as of now. Please describe in detail which raspbian version you have installed and how you try to use Libre Office.

Comment: Just did, is there anything else I should provide? Is there a command that I should type into the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. It turns out that the default account for Raspberry
(username: `pi`, password: `raspberry`) does not have access rights for some functionalities. Therefore I could either do:

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/19549/office-permission/

or just log in as root instead. In order to set a root password, first use

```
sudo passwd root
```

then just switch users to have access rights to everything. That solved it for me, hopefully it will help other beginners that encounter the same trouble.

Comment: Beware using the GUI as root is considered a security risk.